# Typescript - type mapping fails inside a generic function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

Given these Typescript types:

```
// Validation types
type Methods = 'firstName' | 'lastName' | 'email'
type Method<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: Methods }
type Row<T> = keyof T | Method<T>
type Mapping<T> = Array<Row<T>>

// Fields that will be accepted
type Fields = {
  firstName: string
  lastname: string
  e?: string
}
```

And this data:

```
// Data object, holding the form submission
const data: Fields = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  e: 'john@example.com'
}

// Map validation methods to the data fields
const mapping: Mapping<Fields> = [
  'firstName',
  'lastname',
  {
    e: 'email'
  }
]
```

Why does this work:

```
const validationFuncs: Method<Fields>[] = mapping.map(m => {
  return typeof m === 'string' ? { [m]: m } : m;
})

// validationFuncs[0].firstName // works
```

But this doesn't?

```
function validate<T>(mapping: Mapping<T>) {
  const validationFuncs: Method<T>[] = mapping.map(m => {
    return typeof m === 'string' ? { [m]: m } : m;
  })
}
```

[image: Why?]

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using? New versions introduced some stricter generics checking.

Comment: Typescript 2.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of `Method<T>` must be `Methods`, which can only be `"firstName"`, `"lastName"`, or `"email"`.  In your generic example:

```
function validate<T>(mapping: Mapping<T>) {
  const validationFuncs: Method<T>[] = mapping.map(m => {
    return typeof m === 'string' ? { [m]: m } : m;
  })
}
```

the type `T` can be anything... for example, `{nope: string}`.  In this case, `keyof T` is `"nope"`, and the declared type of `validationFuncs` is `{nope?: Methods}[]`.

But if `mapping` is `["nope"]` (a valid `Mapping<{nope: string}>`), then `validationFuncs` will be `[{nope: "nope"}]` at runtime.    But that's not a `{nope?: Methods}[]`, because `validationFuncs[0].nope` is `"nope"` instead of `undefined` or any of the three allowable values for `Methods`.  So the compiler warns you about that.  This all makes sense to me.

---

In your non-generic, "working" example:

```
const validationFuncs: Method<Fields>[] = mapping.map(m => {
  return typeof m === 'string' ? { [m]: m } : m;
})
```

something weird is happening.  `Method<Fields>` is equivalent to

```
type MethodFields = { 
  firstName?: Methods
  lastname?: Methods
  e?: Methods 
}
```

But the type checking of `{ [m]: m }` [isn't working properly because of a TypeScript bug with computed keys](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) which *might* be [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18317) in TypeScript 2.6; not sure.

The compiler should (but does not) realize that `{ [m]: m }` is only guaranteed to be `{firstName:"firstName"}`, `{lastname:"lastname"}`, or `{e:"e"}`, the last two of which are *not* valid `Method<Fields>` elements (notice the lowercase "n" in `lastname`).  Instead, the type checker widens the type of `{ [m]: m }` to something like `{ [k: string]: keyof Fields }`, which is apparently wide enough to match `Method<Fields>`, not that I understand how.  Anyway, it type checks when it shouldn't; it's a bug or a design limitation in TypeScript.

---

In both cases you're not implementing your code in such a way to conform with the types you've declared. I can't tell whether your types are right but the implementation is wrong, or vice versa, or something else.  I hope you have enough information now to make progress.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, great answer. I reached the same conclusion eventually but couldn't figure out the discrepancy. I'm only a few hours into my first Typescript project, and have hit edge cases like this-- some seem to be bugs, others are just naive implementations on my end. This helps a lot, thanks.